# Need to translate a resource file to japanese

Tags: localization, internationalization, localizable.strings

I need to translate a resource file (.resx) with some 1000 odd strings to japanese. Can anyone suggest a tool for that, or may be some online site which could provide the translation. I have already tried a few software but they require a google API v2, which is a paid service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't expect good results from an automated tool. Especially for localization: Sentences are short, very short, sometimes even indivudal words, where basic characteristics such as being singular or plural, being a noun or a verb can't be distinguished. Add to this the lack of context and you have a total recipe for a mission impossible for a machine. Only a human can help. And even a human will require additional context information.

Answer (score 0):

Google API v2 offers 1M characters at price of $20. Quite a good bargain. Why don't you give it a try?

*(...or you can hire a translator to help you translate. His / her salary should be much higher than $20...)*

Comment: Microsoft Translator is free up to 2MB/month.